# AngularJS - ng-options not populating the list of objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Am trying to populate combo box in AngularJS. Below is the controller code.

```
var app = angular.module('app');

app.controller('roadmap', function($rootScope, $scope, $http, $q, leFactory) {
    $rootScope.activityInfoList=[];

    $rootScope.brand_strategy_list=[];
    $rootScope.brand_strategy_csf=[];
    $rootScope.brand_strategy_initiatives=[];

    leFactory.getActivityPopupInfo().then(function(activityList) {
        $rootScope.activityInfoList=angular.copy(activityList);
        console.log($rootScope.activityInfoList);

        $rootScope.brand_strategy_list=$rootScope.activityInfoList.listBrandStrategy;

        console.log($rootScope.brand_strategy_list);

        console.log('editActivityPopup service accepted-> ');
    }, function(error) {
        console.log('editActivityPopup service rejected-> ', error);
    });

    $rootScope.items = [{
      id: 1,
      label: 'aLabel',
      subItem: { name: 'aSubItem' }
    }, {
      id: 2,
      label: 'bLabel',
      subItem: { name: 'bSubItem' }
    }];



});
```

In the HTML part, am trying to populate **$rootScope.brand_strategy_list** as below.

```
    <select ng-model="activityInfoList.brandStrategy" class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-inverse" style="display: none;"  ng-options="item.strategyName as item.strategyName for item in brand_strategy_list">
        <option> Select </option>
     </select>
```

**$rootScope.brand_strategy_list** is not getting populated. But when I tried populating **$rootScope.items**, it is getting populated. I made **console.log($rootScope.brand_strategy_list)** and its showing the complete list.

Dont know what mistake am doing? Pls help me solve this issue. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Don't put everything on $rootScope, put it all on $scope instead and see if that works.

Comment: i have did that and also checked. its not working! any other way to solve this????

Comment: In your call to leFactory, inside the .then() can you console.log activityList, does it have anything in it?

Comment: Why did you set the style to `style="display: none;"`? Are you sure the element is visible?

Comment: ya activityList is displaying the list of objects. i even kept this list in html as {{activityList }} and it is displayed in HTML. But combo box is not getting populated.

Comment: Is `leFactory.getActivityPopupInfo()` using a deferred Promise or is it a simple http get request?

Comment: am using simple $http only

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ng-options="item.strategyName as item.strategyName for item in $root.brand_strategy_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove  style="display: none;" from html and change $rootScope to $scope

```
<select ng-model="activityInfoList.brandStrategy" class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-inverse"   ng-options="item.strategyName as item.strategyName for item in brand_strategy_list">
        <option> Select </option>
     </select>
```